# How to set HTML5 Video element ratio?

Tags: html, html5-video

Is there a way to set video element ratio? I've [tried this method](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp), but it doesn't work for element.

I am using WebRTC to record video from camera, so there is no src attribute in  at the beginning. The reason I want to set the ratio is to avoid the height jump after loading from blob.

I hope there there is a CSS solution, or a solution using a div container.

```
<video data-index={this.props.index} 
controls 
ref={(video)=> {this.videoElem = video}}>
video goes here
</video>

audio, video {

    border: 2px dotted grey; // dottd does not work for video element
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover; // does not work
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to set it while recording, and before the recorded video has been produced? Do you require a fixed constraint size when you gUM? Do you display the live stream somewhere?

Comment: I need to set the video element width/height ratio before recording, since if the ratio is different from camera stream, the size of <video> changes suddenly. It feels the the website jumps, not good for user experience. at the beginning the video is empty, a blank grey area.

Comment: hence my questions. You can not be sure before hand what ratio you will get from your user's camera, except if you request it with fixed constraints

Comment: @Kaiido good to know. I see. I didn't know there is ratio constraints that I can set. Thanks! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints